# Freezing checkpoint files for Inception V3 in TensorFlow 1.2

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow

Using the tutorial here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception, I fined-tuned Inception V3 for a provided set of flower photos.  After training, I am left with the following files: [image]

I would like to convert the .ckpt files to .pb but all the scripts I have found for doing so err.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the freeze_graph script? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py has an example of its usage at the top of the file. If that doesn't work, please post what error messages you see.

Comment: Thank you, @PeteWarden.  What input graph would I use for that?

Comment: If you're using Slim, you'll need to use the export_inference_graph.py script that's here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/export_inference_graph.py